# Get value from two tables . - Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

The query i have been trying to frame in sequelize is below:

```
select count(a.class_id),b.max_entries from class_entries a,classes b where a.class_id=b.id and b.id=1
```

The below code helps me fetch classEntries count but , I need value of maxentries for a class as well, which i don't know how. Please favour.

```
 db.classEntries.count({
        include:{
          model:db.Classes,
          attributes:['maxEntries'],
          where:{id:coachingId}

        }

      }).then(counts=>{
        console.log(counts); 
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the count, as well as all values for `maxEntries`, you could use the `findAndCountAll` method:

```
db.classEntries.findAndCountAll({
  include:{
    model:db.Classes,
    attributes:['maxEntries'],
    where:{id:coachingId}

  }
}).then(result =>{
  const count = result.count;
  const rows = result.rows;
})
```

Inside of `rows`, you would have a list of `classEntries` class instances with the `maxEntries` for each.

Comment: Yes..that's what i used atlast

Comment: All i was thinking was if there is a shortcut, like..I didn't need anything else other than count of classentries and maxentry of class. I didn't need anything else. EVen more precise, i wanted to exactly replicate the query i wrote.

Comment: Ok. `findAndCountAll` would be the shortcut. If you wanted to use the query verbatim, you would need to use `db.query`. Otherwise, Sequelize will form the SQL query itself.